# difference between the pronunciation of "cheating" and "teaching"

Tags: pronunciation

I am a Brazilian speaker, and I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the pronunciation of the words *cheating* and *teaching*.

Comment: why *wouldn't* there be?

Comment: Any reason you think these two words in particular should sound similar? Note that "cheat" starts with a "ch" and ends with a "t", while the ***reverse*** is true of "teach".

Comment: For future reference, finding a common pronunciation of [some word] can be done by Googling "define [some word]" and then clicking on the audio symbol next to the phonetic spelling in the definition box that comes up. (Not sure how well this works if you're using a non-English Google.)

Answer (score 10):

In English, *cheat* /tʃit/ and *teach* /titʃ/ are pronounced differently.
For one thing, the first syllable phoneme in each word is aspirated:

- *teach* /titʃ/, phonetically [tʰitʃ]
- *cheat* /tʃit/, phonetically [tʰʃit]

Why this might be a problem for some learners has to to with at least two things

1. /tʃ/ is an automatic pronunciation for /t/ in some languages when it comes before /i/
   (Italian or Japanese, for instance)
2. final /t/ in some languages is automatically converted to /ti/, and then to /tʃi/
   (Brazilian Portuguese, for instance)

That means that speakers of languages with these features will have difficulty hearing
-- and therefore in producing -- these words. Similar phenomena occur with all English palatal consonants: /ʃ, tʃ, ʒ, dʒ/.

Comment: I didn't know any of this (unsurprisingly), but at least I can now see why the question is "meaningful", and why this answer could be very useful to some learners. Initially I just thought it was trivial in the extreme.

Comment: There's a whole area of applied linguistics called "contrastive linguistics" that deals with this kind of language-learning stumbling blocks due to dysfunctional habits from earlier languages learned. ESL teachers need to know this even more than students.

Comment: thanks for the help John Lawler! Indeed i`m a brazilian,i guess that is the reason for this silly question!

Comment: @davi - If John Lawler took the time to educate so many of us in the community, this is NOT a silly question (although it may have received a better reception had you included some more background information in the question itself).